# Missing the obvious with inconsistently delimited data?

Tags: sas

I have built something in SAS to pull down Yahoo! finance .csv data. The code I have built now works fine and I have built some robust error handling into the code. The problem I have had with the data though is that the .csv feed is unsupported and not clean.

The data is comma delimited, but some of the data also has commas in it. Some of the fields are in quotes and some are not. Also the length of the fields varies wildly as as well. A field like Market Capitlisation for example could run form a few million to hundreds of billions.

As a result, if you pass multiple stock metrics for multiple stocks through to the Yahoo! API at the same time, you will get rows of .csv data where each field is in a different place, is a different length and is inconsistently delimited.

I have tried multiple infile options that could handle some of these errors in isolation, but not all of them together. My only solution that works is to download single stock metrics by multiple stocks at the same time.

This gives me what I want, but it takes over an hour to run the data for the NASDAQ and the NYSE. Have I overlooked another method for handling this type of problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a SAS/CONNECT license?  If so, you can setup a multi process program to do the downloads in parallel.

Comment: Are you actually using the Yahoo! API?  On an earlier question I suggested using the actual API and not just the website interface.  The actual API should have a better formatted result set.

Comment: Perhaps I am ignorantly using internet terminology here. I meant submitting at .csv request to the Yahoo! finance site in the format of 

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s= a BUNCH of STOCK SYMBOLS separated by "+" &f=a bunch of special tags

Is this the website or the API? I'm definitely not using a screenscraper if that is what you mean as the filepath above if you type it into a search engine bar and have MS Office installed downloads the output to an Excel .csv file. If you connect via SAS filename URL the data is downloaded to a dataset instead.

Comment: Re SAS/CONNECT, I just have a basic SAS version 9 licence.

Comment: I think from what I have just read online the above is the API, but the .csv stream is not formally supported by Yahoo.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Did a bit more digging.  There is _not_ an API; in fact, it is explicitly disallowed to redistribute the data from finance.yahoo.com (per their agreements w/ the exchanges). This may or may not affect what you're doing, if you're not redistributing it, but it's why they don't make it very easy to do what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah I had figured that they had made the data dirty to make redistribution more difficult. I don't plan on redistributing the data and I read on a forum previously the T&C's, but thanks for letting me know anyway. Re the API then, is there a better source available from yahoo then? I would've looking for the same level of detail as I currently have though. Every stock by every metric. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the outline of a way to do what you are looking for.  The whole of the code to do this would be too long to post here and out of scope of what this site looks to do.

1. Create a SAS program that takes a stock ticker from the SYSPARM automatic macro, and downloads the data to a data set named the same as the ticker into a permanent library.

   The SYSPARM macro is set by the value you set on the commandline to call SAS

   sas.exe myprog.sas -sysparm XYZ

   This would set &SYSPARM to resolve XYZ
2. Write a SAS program that merges all the ticker data sets together for further processing.
3. Create a program in a language like Perl or Python, (or shell script, etc.) that loops over a range of tickers and calls your SAS program, passing the ticker through SYSPARM.
4. Use a threading, forking, etc. package from that language to have multiple of these running at the same time.  You can probably go to some multiple of the CPU cores on your machine as this processing will not be CPU intensive.  Test values to you find one that works.
5. From that same language call your SAS program to merge the datasets.

Comment: Just bought a beginners book on Python. I thought it was best to do that before I start playing with code I dont really understand. I'm guessing that as Python is broadly C based that it should make the learning of other C based languages quicker and easier?